# NodeJS archive manager

Tags: node.js, npm, archive, node-archiver

I need to get the content of archives and then I want to uncompress the selected one - but I dont want to uncompress the archives to know what's in it. I'd like to list and uncompress at least `zip` and `rar`, but (if that's possible) I don't want to be limited to only these two.

Can you advise good npm modules or other projects to achieve this?

Here's what I came up with:

1. `zip`
   I found [node-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip) can only unzip files, but not list archive content.
2. `rar`
   The best solution seems [node-rar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rar), but I can't install it on Windows.
3. [node-uncompress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-uncompress) This does what it says: It's an "Command-line wrapper for uncompressing various file types." So there is again no possibility to list archive content.

Currently I try to get `node-uncompress` to list files and hopefully it must never run cross-platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

I am now using 7zip with the node module `node-7z` instead of trying to get every archive working on its own. The corresponding site is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-7z

This library uses the OS independent archive manager 7zip. On Windows 7za is used. "7za.exe (a = alone) is a standalone version of 7-Zip". I've tested it on Windows and Ubuntu and it works great.

**Update:**

At Windows: Somehow I just got it working by adding 7za to the Path variables - not by adding *7za.exe* to the "the same directory of your package.json file." like the description says.

**Update 2:**

On Windows *7za*, that's referred in the [node-7z post](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-7z#installation), cannot handle `.rar`-archives. So I'm using the "casual" [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) instead of *7za.exe*. I just renamed the commanline `7z.exe` to `7za.exe` and added the 7-zip folder to the Path Variables.

Comment: FYI - I rewrote node-7z in ES module syntax, added support for configurable 7z.exe / 7za.exe location and published as [es-7z](https://npmjs.com/package/es-7z) in case anyone needs to be able to adjust the path.